# Android SQLite unidirection Sync with SQL Server using Rest API webservice

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services, sqlite

I have an SQL Server Database with quotes. 
The table has four fields ID primary key, Title, Description, and InsertDate.

I have created an Android application to display the quotes. The quotes are downloaded locally to the SQLite database and then displayed using ListView.
Whenever the user clicks the sync button, if any new quotes are added to the SQL Server database it should be downloaded to the SQLite database.

I have created a web service for the syncing using RestApi.

I have never used Webservice and new to Android development. Worked on Asp.net/C#.

My question is:

1. The android application should only download the latest records how to request only the latest inserted record from android using webservice.
2. If I change a record on SQL server how to identify such records and change in the SQLite database.

My current code is logically wrong and I need to change as it is deleting all the records and inserting all the records again. (Wanted to give demo to the customer)

```
        // Create AsycHttpClient object
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    // Http Request Params Object
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    // Show ProgressBar
    prgDialog.show();

    client.get(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.IpAdd) + "/WebApi/api/mpAudioapi/GetAllAudio", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            // Hide ProgressBar
            prgDialog.hide();
            // Update SQLite DB with response sent by getusers.php

            String str;
            try {
                str = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // this should never happen because "UTF-8" is hard-coded.
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }

            updateSQLite(str);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Hide ProgressBar
            prgDialog.hide();
            if (statusCode == 404) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
```

The code to Sync

```
        int writing_counts = dbHandler.getMpAudioRowCount();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersynclist;
    usersynclist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    // Create GSON object
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    try {
        // Extract JSON array from the response
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
        //JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(response);
        //JSONArray arr = responseObject.getJSONArray("results");


        //JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
        System.out.println(arr.length());
        if (writing_counts == arr.length()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry. No new writings to sync.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        dbHandler.truncateTableAudio();
        // If no of array elements is not zero
        if (arr.length() != 0) {
            // Loop through each array element, get JSON object which has Title and Des
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                // Get JSON object
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                System.out.println(obj.get("Id"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("Title_Audio"));
                System.out.println(obj.get("URL_Audio"));
                // DB QueryValues Object to insert into SQLite
                queryValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // Add ID extracted from Object
                queryValues.put("id", obj.get("Id").toString());
                // Add Title extracted from Object
                queryValues.put("title", obj.get("Title_Audio").toString());
                // Add Des extracted from Object
                queryValues.put("url", obj.get("URL_Audio").toString());

                // Insert User into SQLite DB
                dbHandler.insertWriteAudio(queryValues);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // Add status for each User in Hashmap
                map.put("id", obj.get("Id").toString());
                map.put("title", obj.get("Title_Audio").toString());
                map.put("url", obj.get("URL_Audio").toString());
                usersynclist.add(map);
            }
            // Inform Remote MySQL DB about the completion of Sync activity by passing Sync status of Users
            //updateMySQLSyncSts(gson.toJson(usersynclist));
            // Reload the Main Activity
            reloadActivity();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sync activity completed successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My DBhandler Code:

```
    public void truncateTable(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("delete from "+ MP_TABLE);
}

    public void insertWriteAudio(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id", queryValues.get("Id"));
    values.put("title", queryValues.get("title"));
    values.put("url", queryValues.get("url"));
    database.insert("audios", null, values);
    database.close();
}

    public int getMpAudioRowCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long cnt  = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, MP_TABLE_Audio);
    db.close();
    return (int) cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can download only the updated content from database server. This is how you can do that. It will need some changes in your schema -

> **On Server side**
>
> 1. Add one more column in the database, 'Updated_On' which will contain
>      the timestamp when that record was updated on the server
> 2. When you are inserting or updating any new record in the databse,
>      change the 'Updated_On' field accordingly

Now make some changes on the client side

> **On Client Side**
>
> 1. In your Android app, keep a note of what was the last change that
>      was downloaded, i.e. the last download was made for 'Updated_On' =
>      {some past time stamp} (You can do that in SharedPreferences on cancreate a SQLite table)
> 2. When you query to download, query for all records who have
>      'Updated_On' > {some past time stamp}
> 3. If the record exist in your local SQLite database, update it; else insert the record in your SQLite databse

---

To help you get started, where you are making the AsyncHttp call

```
....     
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
// Show ProgressBar
prgDialog.show();
params.put("latestChange",lastUpdateTimestamp);
//where lastUpdateTimestamp is the sharedPreference value you are keeping of last update
client.get(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.IpAdd) + "/WebApi/api/mpAudioapi/GetAllAudio", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
....
```

On your server side you get that post variable `$lastUpdate = $_POST['latestChange']`. Now use the variable $lastUpdate in your API to query the database `Select * from table where Updated_On > $lastUpdate`

Comment: The server side changes is fine. I problem is with the client side code. Can you show with an example how to query for the records after  {some past time stamp}. I can save and retrive the SharedPrefences [You can skip that part].

Comment: I will certainly try this and let you know. Also, hope there is no limit for the number of records. Can I pass more than 10000 records[quotes] when the user Sync the app for the firsttime?

Comment: You can pass, but it will be slow and connection might break. It's better that you do that in batches. What I mean is, when user clicks Sync, download 5000 quotes, then once that is downloaded do another 5000 and so on, till entire data is synced